# List of charecters i Sharpoint Online - æøå

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm making a list to get data from a sharepoint online list usning PowerShell and Connect-PnPOnline. Everything works, except I'm danish and can't find the code for special danis charekters: "æøå". I know that " " (space) is "x0020", but I havent been able to find a full list, or at least my tree "æøå",

Hope you can help, as google failed me (or more likely, i faild to search the right way).

Edit: I've found this list, but no æøå: https://realsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/sharepoint-escape-characters/

Answer (score 0):

You can get PowerShell to figure that out for you :)

```
"æøå".ToCharArray().ForEach({
  '\x{0:X4}:"{1}" - \x{2:X4}:"{3}"' -f +$_,$_,+[char]::ToUpper($_),[char]::ToUpper($_)
})
```

Here, we iterate over each character and print it's underlying unicode value (the unary `+` in front of a char converts it to an integer), then do the same for its uppercase variant, the result of which will look like:

```
\x00E6:"æ" - \x00C6:"Æ"
\x00F8:"ø" - \x00D8:"Ø"
\x00E5:"å" - \x00C5:"Å"
```

Comment: Hi Mathias Thanks for the reply. SharePoint online dont use unicode (which is fustrating), they use their own char-code.. :(

Comment: @ThomasRepsdorph I'm 99% they will overlap - did you give it a try? (eg. with `x00C6` in place of `Æ`)

Comment: I've tried the following, maybe I did something wrong?
$Loesning = if ($itemFields.L_x00F8_sning) { $itemFields.L_x00F8_sning.LookupValue } else { '' }

Comment: And you're sure that's exactly property name? Try `$itemFields |Get-Member L*sning` to verify

Comment: I get the following error:
Unexpected token 'sning.LookupValue' in expression or statement.
At \\nas-groups\groups\sgdrijob\alm\pn0\abr\dw\scripts\KuberDumpToDB_v15.ps1:87 char:78
+ ... ($itemFields.L*sning) { $itemFields.L*sning.LookupValue } else { '' }
+                                                               ~~~~

Does not work: $Loesning = if ($itemFields.L*sning) { $itemFields.L*sning.LookupValue } else { '' }
Works: $Kubeejer = if ($itemFields.Kubeejer) { $itemFields.Kubeejer.Email } else { '' }

And thansk for helping me :)

Comment: @ThomasRepsdorph Try `$itemFields |Get-Member L*sning` or just `$itemFields |Get-Member` and observe what the actual property name(s) are.